# Time-complexity of code containing nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode

```
i := n;
WHILE i > 1
    FOR j := i to n DO
        X;
    END
    FOR j := 3*i to 3*n DO
        X;
    END
    DEC(i); (* i decrement *)
END
```

For this pseudocode, I have to calculate a function f: N -> N, depending on n. I'm doing something like this for the first time, so I don't even know if my approach is correct. So, in the first line I have 1 constant time. The while loop runs n-1 times + n times comparison and n-1 constant time for decrement. The first for loop runs n-i+1 times. The second for loop runs 3n-3i+1 times.
So (I think) that would be the formula: f(n)=1+((n-1)+n+(n-1))*((n-i+1)+(3n-3i+1)) and that would be f(n)=12n^2 -12ni -2n +8i -3

But now I have `n` and `i` variables? How do I get rid of the `i`?

Comment: I think this would be better suited in [computerScience.se](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), maybe?

Comment: The inner loop is `O(n*f(x))` where `f(x)` is the complexity of executing `x`. The outer loop is `O(n)` which makes it: `O(n^2 * f(x))`

Comment: O(n*f(x))? Could you explain, how did you come to this conclusion? Since I have two for-loops. And what about the i?

Comment: You have two inner for-loops, each of which runs in `O(n*f(x))`: which is `n` iterations and the "work" that each iteration requires is a function of `x`: `f(x)`. Since both inner for-loops have the same complexity, we sum them to  `O(n*f(x))`, and since the outer-loop runs `n` times we get total of: ` `O(n^2*f(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that "to n" means "the last value is n-1" (it is not important in terms of time complexity - see the final explanation).

Let's take `f(X)` = the time complexity to run `X`.

The total amount of time is:

```
1 +
0 + 0 +                   // i=n
f(X) + 3*f(X) +           // i=n-1
2*f(X) + 6*f(X) +         // i=n-2
3*f(X) + 9*f(X) +         // i=n-3
...
(n-2)*f(X) + 3*(n-2)*f(X) // i=2
------------------------------
1 + 4*f(X) + 8*f(X) + 12*f(X) + ... + 4*(n-2)*f(X)
```

And this sum is equal to:

```
1 + 4*f(X)*(1+2+3+...+n-2) = 1 + 4*f(X)*(n-2)*(n-1)/2
```

But the constants don't influence the trend for that function => the result is:

```
O(2*f(X)*(n-2)(n-1)) = O(f(X)*(n^2))
```

which is `O(n^2)` if `X` is just a simple operation (`O(1)`).

**P.S.**:

If you are not sure that the constants doesn't influence the final result, just try to calculate:

```
          1 + 4*f(X)*(n-2)*(n-1)/2 
   lim  ---------------------------
n->infinite      f(X)*n^2
```

and you'll obtain a finite number (it means that the numerator and the denominator are similar).